# Integrating trigonometric functions

Tags: integration

It's been a long time since I last integrated trigonometric functions, and there must be clues I am missing. Specifically, I want to integrate the following functions:

(i) $\dfrac{1}{\cosh^2x}$

I know how to integrate $\dfrac{1}{\cosh x}$, namely with substitution and with the equality
$\cosh x = \dfrac{1}{2}(e^x + e^{-x})$ but how do I integrate $\dfrac{1}{\cosh^2x}$

(ii) $\dfrac{\tan x}{\sin(2x)}$ which I think I would rewrite with $\tan x = \sin x/\cos x$ to $\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x\sin(2x)}$ - but I could not progress from there on

as well as:

(iii) $\dfrac{1-\cos^2x}{2\cos^2x}$ - here I think I would substitute the $\cos^2x$ - but again I got stuck..

Any hint is welcome

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with hyperbolic functions, but were it cosine instead of hyperbolic cosine, the answer would be $\int\sec^2xdx=\tan x$.  Searching internet functions with google shows this is similarly the case with hyperbolic functions.

For the second one, the problem is the $\sin 2x$ in the denominator, which can be handled with the double angle formula $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$.  After cleaning up, you're going to end up with a secant squared integral again.

And apparently following the theme from the first and second, the third one can be split into 2 fractions as $\frac12\sec^2x-\frac12$. Or similarly, realize the top is equal to $\sin^2x$, changing the integral to $\int\frac12\tan^2xdx=\frac12\int(\sec^2x-1)dx$.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with $\tan'x=\dfrac1{\cos^2x}$ ? Well, in similar manner, $\tanh'x=\dfrac1{\cosh^2x}$. Also, $\sin2x$

$=2\sin x\cos x$. Can you take it from here ? :-)